# Error to solve for string's (.join)

Tags: python

I am new programmer in python and need help on the block of code from the book **Dive into python** as given below:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.join
<function join at 00C55A7C>
```

This shows *no error* and I tried the very same in the python interactive shell, and I got the following:

```
import string
>>> string.join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    string.join
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'join'
```

I even copied the text from the book to mine shell,but it still does not help.

What should I do?

Comment: @ erip , you mean string is now called or taken by str?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026038/relationship-between-string-module-and-str).

Comment: If you are using Python3, read Dive into Python 3. `string.join` was removed in Python 3. More info in the dupe.