# Functions, methods, and how many arguments do I have to give them?

Tags: python, string, list, function, methods

Why do the following lines give me the same result?

```
str.upper('hello')
```

and

```
'hello'.upper()
```

I tried to do the same with `list.append` but got a `TypeError`.

```
list.append([1])
```

Is the `str` type in Python overloaded? How can this be achieved by writing a class/function? I would appreciate an example.

Comment: at which list you do expect to append 1?

Comment: What would your `list.append([1])` append where?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026038/relationship-between-string-module-and-str

Comment: What's the relation between your first example for upper cases and append an integer to a list?

Comment: *"How can this be achieved by writing a class/function?"* How can what be achieved? It's not at all clear what you are asking for.

Comment: @timgeb They might be related to the unanswered questions in the comments. Mine certainly is.

Comment: This question is only trivial on the surface. +1

Answer (score 7):

`list.append` takes two arguments - the list to modify and the element to append. So you need to do it like this:

```
ls = [1]
list.append(ls, 2)
```

which is equivalent to the much more popular:

```
ls.append(2)
```

Answer (score 6):

`str.upper` and `list.append` are both functions.

`str.upper` takes one argument.

```
>>> str.upper('test')
'TEST'
```

`list.append` takes two arguments.

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> list.append(my_list, 1)
>>> my_list
[1]
```

`str.upper` and `list.append` (like other functions) are also [*non-data-descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html) with a `__get__` method which in this context has two implications:

1. When you access the function through the class via the dot notation (`str.upper`, `list.append`) the function's `__get__` method (i.e. `string.upper.__get__` and `list.append.__get__`) is called but it returns just the function itself.
2. When you access the function through an *instance* (`my_string.upper`, `my_list.append`) the function's `__get__` method is called and it will return a *new callable* acting like the original function, but with whatever was "in front of the dot" automatically passed as the first argument. .

That's why you need to pass 1 - 1 = 0 arguments when calling `my_string.upper()` and 2 - 1 = 1 argument when calling `my_list.append(1)`.

```
>>> 'my_string'.upper()
'MY_STRING'
>>>
>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list.append(1)
>>> my_list
[1]
```

You *could* even get these modified callables (methods) by explicitly calling `__get__` and passing the argument to be bound (what has been before the dot) as its argument.

```
>>> my_string = 'my_string'
>>> upper_maker = str.upper.__get__(my_string)
>>> upper_maker()
'MY_STRING'
>>> 
>>> my_list = []
>>> appender = list.append.__get__(my_list)
>>> appender(1)
>>> my_list
[1]
```

Finally, here's a short example demonstrating how descriptor instances can detect whether they are being accessed via their owner-class or via an instance.

```
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner_class):
        if instance is None:
            print('accessed through class')
            # list.append.__get__ would return list.append here
        else:
            print('accessed through instance')
            # list.append.__get__ would build a new callable here
            # that takes one argument x and that internally calls
            # list.append(instance, x)

class Class:
    attribute = Descriptor()

Class.attribute # prints 'accessed through class'

instance = Class()
instance.attribute # prints 'accessed through instance'
```

Comment: Wouldn't `str.upper` and `list.append` fall under the category of instance method under the `str` and `list` class?

Comment: @Idlehands It's a little word-thinky. If I had to try to be very correct, I would say: `str.upper` and `list.append` are functions that return methods when their `__get__` method is called with a non-`None` `instance` argument - where I would define a method as a callable which partially (i.e. with bound first argument) applies a function defined inside a class.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was genuinely confused because my background is not in comp-sci so terminologies and paradigms are weak spots for me.  My understanding was that any functions defined within a class (i.e. a dot preceding its name) is always a method (instance/class/static) hence my original question.  In this case I figured `str.upper` would have been defined similar as `class str: def upper(self):` where it either runs as `instance.upper()` or `str.upper(instance)`.

Comment: @Idlehand The whole descriptor topic is hard. Rule of thumb when writing code: `my_class.function_name` gives you a function to which you must pass all arguments. `instance_of_class.function_name` gives you a method to which `instance_of_class` is automatically passed as the first argument (usually named `self`).

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [Dave Kirby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206417/dave-kirby)s answer from [Relationship between string module and str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026038/relationship-between-string-module-and-str):

> There is some overlap between the string module and the str type,
>   mainly for historical reasons. In early versions of Python str objects
>   did not have methods, so all string manipulation was done with
>   functions from the string module. When methods were added to the str
>   type (in Python 1.5?) the functions were left in the string module for
>   compatibility, but now just forward to the equivalent str method.
>
> However the string module also contains constants and functions that
>   are not methods on str, such as formatting, character translation etc.

Comment: this is probably the best answer one can give here. Don't understand the -1. Well done.

Comment: It probably got downvoted because it was literally a straight quote from another answer in a related thread.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing at all magical going on with `str` (except that we have a nice syntactic shortcut to creating one using ""). You can write a class that behaves like `str` and `list` to see more clearly what is happening here.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.val=str(arg)

    def do_thing(self):
        self.val = "asdf"

    def do_thing_with_arg(self, arg):
        self.val = "asdf " + str(arg)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.val


my_thing = MyClass("qwerty")

# this is like 'hello'.upper()
my_thing.do_thing()
print(my_thing)
# it prints 'asdf'

my_thing = MyClass("qwerty")

# this is like str.upper('hello')
MyClass.do_thing(my_thing)
print(my_thing)
# it prints 'asdf'

my_thing = MyClass("qwerty")

# this is like my_list.append('qwerty')
my_thing.do_thing_with_arg('zxcv')
print(my_thing)
# it prints 'asdf zxcv'

my_thing = MyClass("qwerty")

# this is like list.append(my_list, 'qwerty')
MyClass.do_thing_with_arg(my_thing, 'zxcv')
print(my_thing)
# it prints 'asdf zxcv'
```

The short version is, you're invoking what looks like an "instance method" *on a class*, but you are supplying the instance ('`self`') yourself as the first argument to the function call.